Compose Multiplatform - TLS sessions are not supported on Native platform on iOs
I'm using Compose Multiplatform and trying to API call. The process is done without any warning on Android but on iOS i facing this error: "TLS sessions are not supported on Native platform". I didn't understand what is the reason. Here are details;
build.gradle.kts (:composeApp)
sourceSets {
    commonMain.dependencies {
        implementation(libs.ktor.client.core)
        implementation(libs.ktor.client.cio)
    }

    androidMain.dependencies {
        implementation(libs.ktor.client.okhttp)
    }

    iosMain.dependencies {
        implementation(libs.ktor.client.darwin)
    }
}


lib.version.toml
[versions]
ktor = "3.0.0-wasm2"

[libraries]
ktor-client-core = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-client-core", version.ref = "ktor" }
ktor-client-darwin = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin", version.ref = "ktor" }
ktor-client-okhttp = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-client-okhttp", version.ref = "ktor" }
ktor-client-cio = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-client-cio", version.ref = "ktor" }

Note: When i'm using ktor version "2.3.9" or "2.3.12" i faced below error:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lio/ktor/client/plugins/HttpTimeout;
at io.ktor.client.engine.okhttp.OkHttpEngine.<init>(OkHttpEngine.kt:31)
at io.ktor.client.engine.okhttp.OkHttp.create(OkHttp.kt:31)
at io.ktor.client.HttpClientKt.HttpClient(HttpClient.kt:43)
at io.ktor.client.HttpClientJvmKt.HttpClient(HttpClientJvm.kt:23)


AppModule.kt (kodein)
val appModule = DI {
    bindSingleton {
        val json = Json { ignoreUnknownKeys = true }
        HttpClient {
            install(ContentNegotiation) {
                json(json, contentType = ContentType.Any)
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}

Note: I don't use CIO engine when creating HttpClient for Ktor. I want to say this because some suggestions for this issue about this one. I try both way (with CIO and without CIO) but the result was not changed.

RepositoryImpl.kt
companion object {
    const val BASE_URL = "https://rit.im/x/xxxx-xxx"
}

val result = httpClient.get {
    url(url)
    header(HttpHeaders.ContentType, ContentType.Application.Json)
}.body<CustomModel>()

I'm trying API call on Compose Multiplatform with Ktor, there is no error on Android but i facing "TLS sessions are not supported on Native platform" error on iOS.

Hah, i found the solution after tried so many things. Just remove the "implementation(libs.ktor.client.cio)" line in build.gradle.kts(:composeApp) from commonMain block
